# Can I use a build.gradle generated String in strings.xml?

Tags: android, string, android-gradle-plugin, android-xml, android-resources

Our app name is defined in my build.gradle flavors as

```
appNameFlavor{
        resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp"
}
```

This is necessary due to a trademark issue in another country.

The name is also used a lot in our strings.xml file by using

```
<!DOCTYPE resources [
    <!ENTITY appname "MyApp">
]>
<resources>
    <string name="activity_intro" translatable="true">&appname; Tour</string>
</resources>
```

This is not ideal because the string is hard coded and needs to be switched for every flavor.

I tried using @strings/app_name instead of MyApp in the entity and while Android Studio actually rendered it correctly, the build failed.

There are several StackOverflow answers mentioning that I should use `<!ENTITY % ents SYSTEM "./res/raw/entities.ent">` instead and simply create those files for each flavor, but the file cannot be resolved.

How could I solve this issue of having a variable app name without putting all the strings that reference the app name into a flavor specific strings.xml file, preferably sticking to the way the app name is currently defined?